# How do I add elements (labels) to a Prometheus query for use in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I'm trying to monitor my network switches and I can get data from it.  But the query doesn't return ifName in the results, so when I graph per interface status I can't label the results with the interface name.

Prometheus query
irate(ifHCOutOctets{job="snmp"}[5m])

Results

```
{ifIndex="cpu",instance="192.168.7.130",job="snmp"}
{ifIndex="g1",instance="192.168.7.130",job="snmp"}
{ifIndex="cpu",instance="192.168.7.130",job="snmp"}
```

This feels like I need a join to add ifName to the result set but I just can figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should have metrics describing your interface (metrics `ifAlias`,`ifDescr` and `ifName` which can be the same):

```
ifDescr{ifAlias="",ifDescr="ether1",ifIndex="cpu",ifName="ether1"} 1
ifDescr{ifAlias="",ifDescr="ether2",ifIndex="g1",ifName="ether2"} 1
```

Then you can apply a multiplication operation to match the metrics with a GROUP instruction to *pull* the labels:

```
irate(ifHCOutOctets{job="snmp"}[5m]) BY(ifIndex) * ON(ifIndex) GROUP_RIGHT ifDescr{job="snmp"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to create a query similar to this. Basically I want to see Interface Description and their utilization.
I followed the above suggestion and made below query but this is not working. Data Source is Victoria Metrics. Can you please suggest what is incorrect?

(irate(ifHCOutOctets{instance="Server1"}5m]) / 125000) / ifHighSpeed{instance="Server1"} by (ifIndex) * on (ifIndex) group_right ifDescr{instance="Server1"}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).